# Installing rvm sh script doesn't source properly, how to

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, curl, rvm

I'm making a shell script to install Apache, MySQL, Postgresql, php5, rvm, ruby and rails, kind like a auto install script, but i have problems with the rvm source and all that, this is what i have so far:

```
autoinstall autoconf automake bison build-essential curl git-core libapr1 libaprutil1 libc6-dev libltdl-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libtool libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libxslt1-dev libyaml-dev ncurses-dev nodejs openssl sqlite3 zlib1g zlib1g-dev
autoinstall git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
autoinstall libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # First try to load from a user install
  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # Then try to load from a root install
  source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
else
  printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"
fi
type rvm | head -1
rvm -v
```

This script get to `type rvm | head -1` and say that `rvm: not found`, i suspect it's the weird case of having to close all bash terminals and reopening because the if also got to the `printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"` but when my script exit i do again the `type rvm | head -1` and it show that is installed correctlly.

Any ideas why this happens inside my shell script?

[Edit]:
I made sure that it runs up until source line, the one not working seems to be the source for the rvm script to be able to use rvm inside the shell script, when i check rvm version inside got an error, but in terminal it gives me a version, why?

Comment: There is no "case of having to close all bash terminals". That's not a thing that exists. They don't interact. Changes to shell startup files don't affect existing shell sessions but they will affect any new ones immediately.

Comment: What shell is that toplevel script running in?

Comment: I just run the shell as: `sudo sh installwebtools.sh`, i base my script for rvm in this link [rvm Scripting](https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting) @Etan Reisner

Comment: I just run the shell as: sudo sh installwebtools.sh, i base my script for rvm in this link rvm Scripting @EtanReisner

Comment: The file you are trying to source explicitly [does not run in `sh`](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/scripts/rvm#L8) (and other shells) presumably because they are missing features it depends on. Try using `sudo bash` instead. (And nothing on that linked page says `sudo sh` anywhere.)

Comment: @EtanReisner It worked, does it change anything using bash instead of shell? could any line of the ones not listed in the description break because of that change in calling the script?, also do yo want to put it in an answer?

Comment: It changes the shell used. Which changes the functionality available as built-ins. It shouldn't, for any reasonable script, change anything more than that. And given that the rvm script in question **explicitly** does not allow being used on shells like `sh` I would assume it is known to work correctly for the shells it allows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are trying to source explicitly [does not run in sh](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/scripts/rvm#L8) (and other shells) presumably because they are missing features it depends on.

Using `sudo bash` to run it instead should fix that problem.